# PHP and HTML Code post

Tags: php, html

This PHP/HTML code works in Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 4, but fails to work everywhere else.  Can anyone spot the reason?

```
<div class="white_content" id="light1"><a onclick="document.getElementById('light1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" href="javascript:void(0)"><b>Close</b>
</a><form target="_blank" method="get" action="http://maps.google.com/maps"><br>Enter your starting address for directions:<br><input type="text" name="saddr">
<input type="hidden" value="6266 W Highway 290, Austin, TX 78735, Austin TX" name="daddr"><input type="hidden" value="en" name="hl"><input type="submit" value="get directions">
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=6266 W Highway 290, Austin, TX 78735, Austin, TX&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=400x330&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:red|label:A|6266 W Highway 290, Austin, TX 78735,Austin, TX&amp;sensor=false"></form></div>
<ul><li> Address 1: 6266 W Highway 290, Austin, TX 78735 Phone: (512) 891-9980 <a onclick="document.getElementById('light1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'" href="javascript:void(0)">Map</a></li></ul></div>
```

To duplicate the error, go to eataustineat.com . Click the tab "All Restaurants" and then click "Austin Pizza Garden".  Now, to the right of the video, find a link that says "Map".  Click it.  A "window" should appear with a map.  You can now add anything or nothing in the field to the left of the "Get Directions" button.  After you click it, the div will disappear and you will be pushed to the front of the website.  This should not happen.  It should always bring up Google maps in another window when you click get directions.

Note: I am using Chrome v 12.0.742.

Comment: What are you not including? I assume this isn't the actual file contents, seeing all of the double quotes that are escaped.

Comment: PHP is rendered server side. If you're having an issue with the browser, it has nothing to do with the PHP on the server...only what is being sent to the browser. Post the rendered HTML instead and we can help.

Comment: The HTML ends in a semicolon and there are end string and combine string elements. This must be a string excerpt without the defining. Could the poster please post the full code.

Comment: So really, the code you copied in to your question has literally **nothing** to do with the problem....

Comment: Where do I need to start looking to find the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why the map doesn't load, it's because of all the spaces and HTML entities in the image source's URL.

Change this:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=6266 W Highway 290, Austin, TX 78735, Austin, TX&zoom=14&size=400x330&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red|label:A|6266 W Highway 290, Austin, TX 78735,Austin, TX&sensor=false

to this:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=6266+W+Highway+290,+Austin,+TX+78735,+Austin,+TX&zoom=14&size=400x330&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red|label:A|6266+W+Highway+290,+Austin,+TX+78735,Austin,+TX&sensor=false

I basically replaced all spaces with a plus sign (+) and all HTML entities (&) into just an ampersand (&).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I copied your code verbatim into [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/fwpL6/) and it works perfectly in Opera 11, Chrome 12, Safari 5, Internet Explorer 9, and Firefox 5.

In fact, they all look reasonably identical, which is something of a feat in and of itself.

Not sure what the problem is.